# Oracle scheduler chain_start status is still running when there are no running job

Tags: oracle

I have a job scheduler to run a chain daily but from `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG` it seems like operation: `chain_start` are still in running status while operation: `chain_run shown` completed. Why is that so?

Besides that, `SELECT * FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS` returns no rows.

What is wrong with the job that the `chain_start` did not complete?

Attached snippet from  USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG

[image: log_fil]

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide with output of the following queries:

```
SELECT *  FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS  WHERE OWNER NOT IN ('SYS');
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS WHERE OWNER NOT IN ('SYS');
```